# Как заставить работать автоинкремент при добавлении записи в таблицу Mysql?

Tags: mysql, yii2

Имеется таблица `Test (id(primary AUTO_INCREMENT), text)`
Делаю:

```
$test = new Test();
$test -> text = 'test1';
$test -> save();
```

предполагаю, что в поле `id` запишется автоинкрементное значение, но нет...запись не сохраняется вообще. `$test->getErrors()` говорит "ID cannot be blank."

Если делать так, то всё работает:

```
$test -> id = 1;
$test -> text = 'test1';
$test -> save();
```

Как сделать так чтобы не указывать явно значение поля `id`?

Comment: видимо id зачем-то вписан в rules() у модели

Comment: воистину! Так и есть, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Проверьте метод `rules()` модели, ответственный за валидацию, в нем не должно быть правил для поля `id`.